# find all Latitude Longitude locations within a certain distance from a given Lat Lng location

Tags: java, spring

Given a database of places with Latitude + Longitude locations, such as 51.047260, -114.081550, how would I find all locations within a given distance of a specific location from database entries?

say if Latitude and Longitude are given i have to find a list of values in table which falls under given distance from a specific location

Answer (score 1):

I would have added this as a comment if I was qualified (I'm almost there ..)

Consider using a database solution that is built for this purpose such as the PostGIS extension of PostgreSQL: https://postgis.net/

PostGIS provides many geometry/geography types and functions, such as ST_DWITHIN which could do what you ask: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html